# Resize image in table below 100% when resizing window

Tags: html, image, html-table, resize, shrink

I think similar questions have been answered, but none really seem to have helped me out that much.

I have a table that is set to `width="100%"` with a cell on the top row.
This cell contains an image which is fairly wide.
When I resize the window, and therefore the table, the image does not resize below 100% of its original size.

Is there a way to get this image to reduce in size as the table shrinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to actually get smaller than the specified width/height (or the original width/height) of the image, you need to do some scripting. This means you can hook up the resize event of the browser and reset the width/height of the image equally while resizing.

Another option is to wrap the image in a div with an overflow:hidden specified. So if the div gets to large for the window, it will hide the pieces of the image that fall outside the window.

Comment: I have given the div tag method a go, but for some reason does not appear to work, although I am using inline styling rather than an attached stylesheet. I think scripting will be my next plan of actioon. Thanks, Eds

Comment: I guess you are right about the div overflow not working (just checked it). Sorry about that. The scripting approach must be a better option. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Set image width to 100% as well.

If this doesn't help set it to auto!

```
#img{width:100%;}
```

or

```
#img{width:auto;}
```

Comment: With a width of 100%, the image gets stretched out to fit the cell..width a width specified as auto nothing happens.

Comment: Hi, have tried both of the above, but the image does not appear to resize. is it possible that the width:100%; is actually referring to its original dimensions? so its 100% of original size rather than cell size?

Comment: This seems to be working
`<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <table style="width:100%;">
  <tr><td style="width:100%;" colspan="3">
   <img src="http://www.webwallpapers.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/Lamborghini-prototype-car-926.jpg" style="width:100%;"> 
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
  <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>`